# Oracle UCM login page do not redirects to home page

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic11g, webcenter, oracle-ucm, stellent

I installed Oracle webcenter content 11g(UCM) 11.1.8, IBR and weblogic 10.3.6. I created domain and started the server successfully but i when i go to the UCM application front end and login for the first time with weblogic username-password, it do not redirects me to the home page.It does nothing.

Point to note:-

-However , when i enter with wrong username/password, it does give "Invalid Username/Password" notification.

-I have checked UCM logs and there is no error in it.

- IBR front end is opening fine
- I installed UCM on Adminserver and no managed server is used
- I have parallely installed WCS , created diffirent domains for both WCC & WCS
- I have installed UCM before with the same installation steps(I think so) & everytime it used to work fine.

What i'm missing now?

Comment: Can anyone help? @jonathan-hult

Answer (score 0):

Strange but true. i'm able to login successfully in UCM via other browsers :) 
Not sure, what hampers IE to allow me login as I'm able to login to IBR in IE.Thnx